# Android first applicaiton all my views are skewed

Tags: android, layout

I created my first application. learning Android now. 
this is my main activity:

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”utf-8”?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/
android”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
Creating Your First Android Application ❘ 25
android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
android:orientation=”vertical” >
<TextView
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:text=”@string/hello” />
<TextView
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:text=”This is my first Android Application!” />
<Button
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:text=”And this is a clickable button!” />
</LinearLayout>
```

But my items on the layout are skewed. Can anyone help, please?

Here is the link of the view

http://screencast.com/t/JmA3r48rosjM

Much Thanks,

T

Comment: Is this compiling well ?

Comment: It is. but it is all skewed

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is my first Android Application!" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="And this is a clickable button!" />
```

Try this in your xml file that should be work :)

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work. I keep getting the same same skwed interface. where does the placement take place. I think I should keep reading the book until that is explained. The thing though, I thought I would fix this before going to the next chapter.